# cordova-plugin-network-information supports IPV6 wifi detection

Tags: cordova

Does cordova-plugin-network-information supports IPV6 wifi detection?

I only have resources to set up IPv4 and not IPv6. iOS apps requires all apps to support IPv6 wifi connection. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently also using cordova-plugin-network-information v1.2.1 for our Cordova based app. Our app has been rejected multiple times by Apple due to IPv6 issue since July. It seems that this plugin is currently not compatible with Apple's IPv6 requirements.

Please refer below issue track 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11505

Our current plan is to remove this plugin and would then re-try with Apple Review.

Comment: my app has got accepted already. It was other issue but Apple has conveniently labelled it as incompatible with IPv6. i tested with IPv6 and it was working ok.

Comment: Good to know that. Apple rejected us and labelled as IPv6 compatibility issue. Do you mind to share what your app's issue was? We are striking with Apple's rejection.

Comment: It was a UI issue, we weren't clear in our instructions to the user.

Comment: FYI. We removed cordova-plugin-network-information (also some small tweak for our app) and then finally passed Apple's review.